# How do I make my if statement actually do something

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def attempt_function():
    number_of_attempts = 1
    saidpassword = ""
    if number_of_attempts > 3:
        print("You have entered the wrong password too many times, please try again later")
    saidpassword = input("the password you entered is incorrect, please try again\n")
    if saidpassword != password:
        number_of_attempts + 1
        saidpassword = input("the password you entered is incorrect, please try again\n")
```

the `if number_of_attempts > 3:` doesn't seem to work when I use all of my attempts. It basically doesn't print.

Comment: Because `number_of_attempts` is not greater than 3.

Comment: If you are allowing 3 attempts, you probably want a loop in there somewhere.

Comment: The very first thing the function does is set `number_of_attempts` to `1`.  Under no circumstances will `1` ever be greater than `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def attempt_function():
    number_of_attempts = 0
    saidpassword = ""
    
    while saidpassword != password:
        number_of_attempts + 1
        saidpassword = input("the password you entered is incorrect, please try again\n")
        if number_of_attempts > 3:
            print("You have entered the wrong password too many times, please try again later")
            break
        saidpassword = input("the password you entered is incorrect, please try again\n")
```

You will need a while loop to increase the number of attempts